# Are there other non-trivial invariant subspaces of a linear operator other than the eigenspaces and their combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Assume a linear operator $A$ is not diagonalisable. Let $E_{\lambda i}$ be the eigenspaces corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. I know that $E_{\lambda i}$ is an invariant subspace of $A$, and that $E_{\lambda i} \bigoplus E_{\lambda j}$ are others, but are these **all** the non-trivial invariant subspaces? Meaning are there invariant subspaces I could miss by going for the Eigenspaces and their combinations?

I've found a lot of similar topics to this, but I haven't found any solid proof for non-diagonalisable operators. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Jordan blocks are invariant subspaces which does not need to coincide with (a direct sum of) eigenspaces.

Comment: @18cyclotomic Thanks, I didn't think of that. Still, are there others? Or can you show somehow that the generalised eigenspaces are not reducible further?

Comment: You also have to consider subspaces of eigenspaces.  For example, every subspace is an invariant subspace of the identity operator